# Test structure of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a simplified dataframe as follows:

```
test <- data.frame(
        x = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA),
        y = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, NA),
        a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE)
        )
```

I want to test if when there's NA in column `x`, there will always be a numeric value in column `y` AND when there's a numeric value in column 'x', there will always be a NA in column y. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: `anyNA(test$x)`, and if your statement about `y` being numeric needs to be tested, `is.numeric(test$y)`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: thanks @Maël! I've updated the question a bit. The expected output is TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
(is.na(test$x) & is.numeric(test$y) & !(is.na(test$y))) |
  (is.na(test$y) & is.numeric(test$x) & !(is.na(test$x)))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table(is.na(test[is.na(test$x),]$y))
```

This will tell you the counts of NAs in column *y* if *x* is *NA* in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(test[c('x', 'y')], \(x) is.numeric(x) & is.na(x))) == 1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a TRUE/FALSE on whether the condition works

```
library(dplyr)

is_valid_1 <- test %>%
  filter(is.na(x)) %>%
  all(!is.na(y))

is_valid_2 <- test %>%
  filter(!is.na(x)) %>%
  all(is.na(y))
```